# PrimeNg- Sidebar Module not displaying correctly

Tags: angular, primeng, angular7

[image]I am trying to create a right sidebar1 Navigation (which opens on click of `btn1`) and inside that there should open another sidebar Navigation  from top(which opens on click of `btn2`) where sidebar2  should be outside overlay as long as it is opened.(overlay is not correct for each sidebar).

I am using this primeng link- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/sidebar

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-4gf9tj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Note:- when sidebar1 opens, a black backdrop is over full screen likewise when sidebar2 opens from top there should be black backdrop on sidebar1.

Comment: Please accept the answer that solved your problem. Or paste your own solution in case you've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

As per primefaces [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/sidebar).

> baseZIndex    -number -   0-  Base zIndex value to use in layering.

You need to apply `z-index` as `-1` to the layer, it is appearing to be on top of it.

like this

```
<button (click)="openTab()">btn1</button>
<p-sidebar class="menuPanel" [(visible)]="opened" position="right" [showCloseIcon]="true" autoZIndex="true" baseZIndex="-1">
Sidebar1
<button (click)="openTab2()">btn2</button>
    <p-sidebar class="menuPanel" [(visible)]="filterStatus" position="top" [showCloseIcon]="true" autoZIndex="false" baseZIndex="-1">
       sidebar2
    </p-sidebar>
</p-sidebar>
```

**EDIT:**

So, this seems to be not a problem with the primeng

I believe you forgot to include the theme style

I added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

as per stated [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

and it works great now

here is the changed things

```
<button (click)="openTab()">btn1</button>
<p-sidebar class="menuPanel" [(visible)]="opened" position="right" [showCloseIcon]="true" autoZIndex="true" baseZIndex="99999">
Sidebar1
<button (click)="openTab2()">btn2</button>
    <p-sidebar class="menuPanel" [(visible)]="filterStatus" position="top" [showCloseIcon]="true" autoZIndex="false" baseZIndex="9999999">
       sidebar2
    </p-sidebar>
</p-sidebar>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-saphm2)

Comment: overlay is not displaying & behaving for sidebar2 correctly as it is for sidebar1. Please have a look at above image. Its a top sidebar above right sidebar with overlay for each sidebar display correct onclick of correcponding buttons..

Comment: @Mahi I believe you are using it wrongly, please check my edit and demo link it works great now.

Comment: the overlay(backdrop/ black background below) is not displaying on sidebar1 when sidebar 2 is open from top. As when sidebar1 opens, a black backdrop is  over full screen likewise when sidebar2 opens from top there should be black backdrop on sidebar1. If Possible, is there way in primeNg rather than doing it custom.

Comment: @Mahi please edit your question and add what you tried i will look at it

Comment: @Mahi do you want to close the first sidebar once the second one opens? or keeping it open?

Comment: Keeping  it open... Just a backdrop of background black with events disabled when sidebar2 is opened on sidebar1